# How do I configure tomcat6 with a host name?

Tags: java, tomcat6

I'm trying to deploy the WAR file of Apache Shindig to an apt-installed Tomcat 6 server on Ubuntu 10.04. Unfortunately, when it writes out things like `<script>` tags, all the URLs are `http://localhost/...`, even though I *think* I've told Tomcat that this server has an external name.  The non-comment contents of my `server.xml` file are here. This is essentially the default configuration, save for that I've changed all instances of `localhost` to `my.external.hostname` (of course, my *actual* hostname in the actual configuration file).

How do I get Tomcat6/Shindig to realize that it lives at `my.external.hostname` so it doesn't refer to `http://localhost/...`?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- *** THIS IS WHERE IT GETS INTERESTING: hostname set here: -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="my.external.hostname">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
             resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      <!-- *** and here: -->
      <Host name="my.external.hostname"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there's a *separate settings file* for Shindig that isn't mentioned in the setup documentation. You have to edit the `WEB-INF/classes/containers/default/container.js` file in order to change the host name. There are a bunch of places that use `${HOST_NAME}` or `localhost`, which I changed to `my.external.hostname`. Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this bug entry [Shindig Jira Issue 272](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHINDIG-272)? At least in last December there were no news on a potential resolution. Obviously some hard coded paths are in the way of using a different servlet container than Jetty if your hostname should not be localhost. There is a temporary solution described in the Jira ticket. Does it work for you?

Comment: That seems to deal more with the path in the deployment; I have mine at ROOT...